# Python async API requests in batches

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I m tryin to make async API calls this way:

1. func to send request:

> ```
> async def get_data(client, postdata):
>     res = await client.post(url=_url, headers=_headers, data=postdata)
>
>     return res
> ```

2. func to parse JSON:

> ```
> async def parse_res(client, postdata):
>     
>     res = await get_data(client, postdata)
>     
>     if bool(json.loads(res.text)['suggestions']):
>         _oks = <...grab some JSON fields...>
>     else:
>         _oks = {}
>     return _oks
> ```

3. I wrap this two funcs in MAIN():

> ```
> async def main(_jobs):
>     
>     async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
>         
>         batch = []
>         calls = []
>     
>         for job in _jobs:
>
>             _postdata = '{ "query": "'+ job + '" }'
>
>             calls.append(asyncio.create_task(parse_res(client, _postdata)))
>             
>         batch = await asyncio.gather(*calls)
>             
>         return batch
> ```

and then just run MAIN()

But the API can handle about 30-50 fast (nearly simultaneous requests or throws 429 HTTP error).

So i need to send batches of 30 calls and process 10 000 requests in chunks.

How do i process 10 000 (ten thousand) API calls in batches of 30 ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use Simon Hawe's answer, however here's a different approach without the usage of external libraries

Use `asyncio.Semaphore` to limit the amount of calls made concurrently, when the semaphore is released it will let another function to run.

```py
import asyncio

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(30)  # no. of simultaneous requests

async def get_data(client, postdata):
    async with sem:
        res = client.post(url=_url, headers=_headers, data=postdata)
    return res


async def parse_res(client, postdata):
    res = await get_data(client, postdata)
    if bool(json.loads(res.text)['suggestions']):
        _oks = <...grab some JSON fields...>
    else:
        _oks = {}
    return _oks


async def main(_jobs: int):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        postdata = '{"query": "' + job + '"}'
        calls = [
            asyncio.create_task(parse_res(client, postdata)
            for _ in range(_jobs)
        ]

        return await asyncio.gather(*calls)
```

Answer (score 2):

One library that comes in handy here is funcy. It offers various helper for working with sequences. One of that would be chunks. This allows you to split a sequence into chunks of equal size or fewer in the end if the totalsize does not divide.

```py
from funcy import chunks
result = []
for job_chunk in chunks(30, _jobs):
    calls = [parse_res(client, '{ "query": "'+ job + '" }') for job un job_chunk]
    batch = await asyncio.gather(*calls)
    result.extend(batch)
```